# Lebesgue integrability of step functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

A step function can be defined to be a linear combination of a sequence of brick functions. My question is - Are step functions always Lebesgue integrable ?

Comment: Note that if $s$ is a step function and if $a_{k}$ is the value of $s$ on a subinterval $I_{k}$, then $a_{k}$ times the length of $l_{k}$ equals $a_{k}$ times the length of the preimage of $\{a_{k} \}$ under $s$.

Answer (score 1):

No: Consider the step function $$s(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = 0\\n^2 & {1\over n+1} < x \le {1\over n}, \ n \in \Bbb N_+\end{cases}$$
It is measurable, but not integrable on $[0,1]$.